# Custom control in DataGrid OnRender issue

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I am using this example:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/A-Searchable-Highlight-d7b911f3

in order to leverage highlighting for items in my `DataGrid`.

`SearchableTextControl` derives from `Control`.

```
<logAnalyzer:SearchableTextControl 
                         IsHighlight="True" 
                         Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content.Text}"
                         SearchText="{Binding ElementName=SearchTermTextBox, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                         FontSize="15"
                         Margin="3,0"
                         IsMatchCase="False"/>
```

This is the XAML where i am setting the `Text`, and `SearchText` properties.

All works fine when i am loading the `Window`.

[image]

As shown in the image above the ID 100 has the last column without value and that's fine for my scenario.

But if i scroll down just a bit, and go up again, that row is somehow populated.

[image]

I think the problem comes from the OnRender overriden method:

```
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        // Define a TextBlock to hold the search result.
        TextBlock displayTextBlock = this.Template.FindName("PART_TEXT", this) as TextBlock;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Text))
        {
            base.OnRender(drawingContext);

            return;
        }
        if (!this.IsHighlight)
        {
            displayTextBlock.Text = this.Text;
            base.OnRender(drawingContext);

            return;
        }

        displayTextBlock.Inlines.Clear();
        string searchstring = this.IsMatchCase ? (string)this.SearchText : ((string)this.SearchText).ToUpper();

        string compareText = this.IsMatchCase ? this.Text : this.Text.ToUpper();
        string displayText = this.Text;

        Run run = null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchstring) && compareText.IndexOf(searchstring) >= 0)
        {
            int position = compareText.IndexOf(searchstring);
            run = GenerateRun(displayText.Substring(0, position), false);

            if (run != null)
            {
                displayTextBlock.Inlines.Add(run);
            }

            run = GenerateRun(displayText.Substring(position, searchstring.Length), true);

            if (run != null)
            {
                displayTextBlock.Inlines.Add(run);
            }

            compareText = compareText.Substring(position + searchstring.Length);
            displayText = displayText.Substring(position + searchstring.Length);
        }

        run = GenerateRun(displayText, false);

        if (run != null)
        {
            displayTextBlock.Inlines.Add(run);
        }

        base.OnRender(drawingContext);
    }
```

The above method calls this:

```
    private Run GenerateRun(string searchedString, bool isHighlight)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchedString))
        {
            Run run = new Run(searchedString)
            {
                Background = isHighlight ? this.HighlightBackground : this.Background,
                Foreground = isHighlight ? this.HighlightForeground : this.Foreground,

                // Set the source text with the style which is Italic.
                FontStyle = isHighlight ? FontStyles.Italic : FontStyles.Normal,

                // Set the source text with the style which is Bold.
                FontWeight = isHighlight ? FontWeights.Bold : FontWeights.Normal,
            };
            return run;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I've made a lot of tests but i can't find where this problem comes from. Also i've added a handler for a double click event on that `DataGridRow`:

[image]

And this is correct, the value for the last column is empty, but then, how do i get it populated in the view?